Why does the Node Tree to Find the outer edges and outer perimeter of a mesh in Geometry nodes no longer works in blender 4.3?
Just like the title says, I have been using this node tree to find out the outer mesh perimeter, but this node tree makes the mesh disappear and no longer work in 4.3. I first tried to open a file with this tree in 4.3, but it refused to open (it still works in 4.0). Then I recreated the same tree in a new file in 4.3, only to find that it doesn't work. The screenshot of the tree is in the picture. I swapped out the "equal" in the compare node with "not equal" when I wanted the inner edges instead (for some reason using the node tree for the inner edges gives me the result of the outer edge, and I can't seem to find out how to fix the Inner edge node tree). Any help fixing or replacing these 2 node trees would be greatly appreciated.
This is the setup that still works in Blender 4.0:
Compare node: Equal (for outer edge)
Compare node: Not Equal (for inner edge)



Is your mesh sane? (Aren't there duplicated edges? If it's a flattened cube, for instance, it certainly will not work.

And maybe what you want is "separate geometry" instead of "duplicate"?

@Daniel Möller I had used a grid then deleted some faces. I don't know why, since it still works in 4.0, but you mentioned if there were duplicated edges. I decided to use the merge by distance node, and it suddendly worked like it's supposed to. Thank you, although I am still confused why it still works in 4.0 and not 4.3 without the extra node.

Are you sure you used the "same file" in both versions? Sometimes we edit the same thing and by accident make some mistake.

Yes, I did. I opened the same file without editing it multiple times going between the 4.0 version and the 4.3 version. It wouldn't open for some reason in the 4.3 version. When I appended the collection with the node tree from the unedited file in 4.3, blender crashed each time. I then remade the same node tree in 4.3, but then it didn't work until I added "merge by distance". Only this file's geometry nodes couldn't open for some reason in 4.3, while it worked just fine in 4.0.
